A map between surfaces contracting a curve
Suppose $M,N$ are algebraic surfaces, $C$ is a smooth curve on $M$. If there is a map $f:M\rightarrow N$ contracting $C$ to a point $P$ on $N$, and $f$ is one-to-one from $M\setminus C$ to $N\setminus\{P\}$, then is $f$ always a blow-down?

What is $C\cdot C$ in $M$?

Any projective birational morphism is the blowup of an ideal.

So is there a such birational map when $C\cdot C\not=-1$? And is it true when $C\cdot C=-1$? I want geometric examples since I am not familiar with algebra, thanks.

It seems that I find a positive answer in Barth-Hulek-Peters-Ven's book Compact Complex Surfaces [thm4.2, p98].

If you don't assume smoothness $C\cdot C$ need not be $-1$.
